# How to pass array by HiddenType?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I'm having trouble, I'm trying to pass an array by a form to the twig template, the idea I had is to pass it via an HiddenType.

I can pass a string, but I can't pass an array, I get an "Array to string conversion" error.

Here is the code :

```
$builder->add(
                'existingManagementWorkUnitLabels',
                HiddenType::class,
                [
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => $existingManagementWorkUnitLabels,
                ]
            )
```

If someone has an idea.
Thank you.

Comment: You could add a Collection of HiddenType as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about serializing the array and doing it like this:

```
$builder->add(
                'existingManagementWorkUnitLabels',
                HiddenType::class,
                [
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'data' => serialize($existingManagementWorkUnitLabels),
                ]
            )
```

Within twig you can do:

```
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('unserialize', 'unserialize'); 
$twig->addFilter($filter);
```

and then:

```
do {% for value in (array|unserialize) %}
```

Comment: Where do I write this ?  $filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('unserialize', 'unserialize'); 
$twig->addFilter($filter);

Comment: Check the docs: https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/advanced.html#filters